# Is there a way that you are able to pull in an rendered image from blender and resize/resample it using Python?

Tags: python, pixel, blender, image-resizing, resample

I am needing to pull a 200m square image with something that I build in blender and resample it using python. Main goal is to change the pixel size of the image.

Any suggestions on what to even write in python?

Thanks.

I am not sure how to resample an image on python.

Comment: Assuming you have saved the rendered output to a raster format like .png or .jpg, try using the Pillow library: https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/